# cURL looking for CA in the wrong place

Tags: php, https, curl, certificate-authority

On Redhat Linux, in a PHP script I am setting cURL options as such:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/home/andrew/share/cacert.pem');
```

Yet I am getting this exception when trying to send data

```
(curl error: 77) error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
```

Why is it looking for the CAfile in `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`? I don't know where this folder is coming from as I don't set it anywhere.

Shouldn't it be looking in the place I specified, `/home/andrew/share/cacert.pem`? I don't have write permission `/etc/` so simply copying the file there is not an option. Am I missing some other curl option that I should be using?

(This is on shared hosting - is it possible that it's disallowing me from setting a different path for the CAfile?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Replacing CURLOPT_CAINFO with CURLOPT_CAPATH.

And also take a look at SSLCERT option.